# SQL Refactor Rename Not Publishing Correctly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to rename a few tables in one of my database projects. I right click and choose "Refactor" then choose "Rename". The Rename process appears to be working great! All references to the table are updated correctly and the refactorlog file is updated with an appropriate "Rename Refactor" operation.

However; when I generate a script to publish changes, the script simply creates a new table rather than going through the process of creating a new table, then copying the old table's data over, and finally (presumably) dropping the old table.

I've also tried just renaming a column on the table which results in a new column and dropping of the old one. The data should be copied over to the new column via a new table/identity insert/rename.

I've run a repair of SSDT just to be sure and had no success. Any advice is welcome!

-- Update --

I've not yet resolved this issue but it should be noted that the original DB project was created with an earlier version of visual studio (2010 regular) than we are currently using (2013 ultimate). The project was working in terms of refactoring in our current version of visual studio until recently.

Comment: Update: I've rebuilt one of my database projects by creating a new project and re-importing the structure from the live db. The resulting project successfully refactors and builds a proper refactoring deploy script. I'm going to work towards building my db projects accordingly. If I figure out what happened, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completely recreating my db project, I had *some* success but it was inconsistent. After a few publish tests, it started to act inconsistently Some refactors would take while others would drop the original table and then begin creating a new one with the new definition.

It turns out I had multiple versions of SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) installed (2012 and 2013). I uninstalled 2012 and then ran a repair of 2013. Viola! Refactoring is now working again.